# MDN webRTC still photo capture demo stops working recently

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I followed [MDN's webRTC still photo capture](http://mdn-samples.mozilla.org/s/webrtc-capturestill/) in my own program. It worked well two months ago. Today, when trying the same program, I found that no video input from the webcam can be displayed. In fact, the demo provided by MDN cannot work too. I tried both Chrome Version 66 and Firefox Version 60.0.2 and met the same issue. Does anyone know what has happened on browsers' side causing webRTC failing?

Answer (score 1):

This attempts to set mozSrcObject which has been removed a few Firefox releases ago. Try setting the video elements srcObject to the stream instead -- in any (modern) browser.

The [original article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos) also contains relatively up-to-date code

Answer (score 0):

Finally, found the error reason. In capture.js line 47, need to make the following update. Please see [More information about the issue](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC/issues/326)

```js
// Don't do this
video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);

// Do this
video.srcObject = stream;
```